# F# Interface Implementation Error

Tags: c#, interface, f#

I'm trying to implement the following interface in F#:

```
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using UIKit;

namespace Softweb.Xamarin.Controls.iOS
{
    [Protocol (Name = "ZLSwipeableViewDataSource", WrapperType = typeof(CardViewDataSourceWrapper))]
    public interface ICardViewDataSource : INativeObject, IDisposable
    {
        //
        // Methods
        //
        [Export ("nextViewForSwipeableView:"), Preserve (Conditional = true), CompilerGenerated]
        UIView NextCardForCardView (CardView cardView);
    }
}
```

To do so I have the following code:

```
[<Register ("BackgroundAnimationViewControllerDataSource")>]
type BackgroundAnimationViewControllerDataSource () =
    interface ICardViewDataSource with 
         member this.NextCardForCardView(cardView : CardView) = 
            let card = new UIView()
            card.Frame <- CGRect()
            card.BackgroundColor <- UIColor.Blue
            card.Layer.ShouldRasterize <- true
            card
```

However this gives me the error:

`No implementation was given for 'ObjCRuntime.INativeObject.get_Handle() : nativeint'. Note that all interface members must be implemented and listed under an appropriate 'interface' declaration, e.g. 'interface ... with member ...'.`

I don't understand this as there is no additional methods in the interface.

Comment: I'm no expert in F#, but it looks like you're not implementing the `Handle` property which is part of the [`INativeObject`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.INativeObject/) interface.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Not sure how to fix that

Comment: I think @DavidG is correct. Take a look [at this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/interfaces#interface-inheritance). You're going to need to implement all of the members of `INativeObject` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your `ICardViewDataSource` interface also implements [`INativeObject`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.INativeObject/). This means you need to implement all members of that interface too. In this case, there's a property called [`Handle`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.INativeObject.Handle/) that is missing.

Also worth noting that it implements [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) which means you may need to have a `Dispose` method too.